# Does commitedit() change the properties of it's object?

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8

I was wondering if the commitEdit() method of a TableCell in JavaFX updates the property of the object the row represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`TableView` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html):

> By default the `TableColumn` edit commit handler is non-null, with a
>   default handler that attempts to overwrite the property value for the
>   item in the currently-being-edited row. It is able to do this as the
>   `Cell.commitEdit(Object)` method is passed in the new value, and this is
>   passed along to the edit commit handler via the `CellEditEvent` that is
>   fired. It is simply a matter of calling
>   `TableColumn.CellEditEvent.getNewValue()` to retrieve this value.
>
> It is very important to note that if you call
>   `TableColumn.setOnEditCommit(javafx.event.EventHandler)` with your own
>   `EventHandler`, then you will be removing the default handler. Unless
>   you then handle the writeback to the property (or the relevant data
>   source), nothing will happen. You can work around this by using the
>   `TableColumnBase.addEventHandler(javafx.event.EventType,
>   javafx.event.EventHandler)` method to add a
>   `TableColumn.EDIT_COMMIT_EVENT` EventType with your desired `EventHandler`
>   as the second argument. Using this method, you will not replace the
>   default implementation, but you will be notified when an edit commit
>   has occurred.

So by default, calling `commitEdit(...)` cause the `TableColumn` to attempt to update the value represented by the cell. If you set an event handler by calling `TableColumn.setOnEditCommit(...)`, you remove the default behavior.

Note also that the default mechanism works by casting the object returned by the column's `cellValueFactory` to a `WritableValue`, and calling its `setValue()` method. So this will (essentially) only work if the backing model for the table uses the [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107). In other words, you should have something equivalent to

```
column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().xxxProperty());
```

where the `xxxProperty()` method in the model for your table returns an implementation of `WritableValue` (e.g. a `Property` object).

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to fix the problem I had.